# How do I set shipping value depending on select & checkbox

Tags: jquery

In my form have `select`, `checkbox` & `input` field.

The input field is for digital product. If user just put amount on the input & set shipping price is 0. If input with select or checkbox shipping price will be 10.

How do I get correct shipping value.

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.price', function() {
  var total = 0;
  var shipping = 0;
  var digital = $("#digital").val();

  $('#form option:selected, #form input:checked').each(function() {
    if (digital != 0) {
      shipping = 0;
    } else {
      shipping = 10;
    }

    total += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price")) || 0;
  });

  $('.total').html('$ ' + (parseFloat($("#digital").val()) + total + shipping).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="number" name="digital" id="digital" class="price" value="0">

  <select name="book" id="book" class="price">
    <option data-price="0" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option data-price="10.00" value="1">Book A</option>
    <option data-price="15.00" value="2">Book B</option>
  </select>

  <input data-price="7.80" class="price" name="covers[]" type="checkbox" value="1">White
  <input data-price="7.80" class="price" name="covers[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Black

  <div class="total"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean with `digital product`... that the user only gets it digital or physical? and if yes, why can you select diffrent values ? I mean if it's so, there can only be 2 possibilitys. `Yes` and `No` **(1/0)**

Comment: @Dwza it like a token. we put a token value `#digital`. If use buy token only shipping is 0. If with book & cover including shipping price

Comment: but evertying seams to work like expacted... so I dont get the point ^^

Comment: You may try select or checkbox first. Select deselect checked & unchecked

Comment: So you mean If something gets selected and than deselected that there is still shippingcosts ?

Comment: Yes.. sometime it will be NaN.

Comment: did my answere helped  you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an IF

```
if(!total)
    shipping = 0;
```

So it should look like

```js
$(document).on('change keyup', '.price', function() {
  var total = 0;
  var shipping = 0;
  var digital = $("#digital").val();
  var test = $("#book option:selected").data("price");


  $('#form option:selected, #form input:checked').each(function() {

    if (digital != 0) {
      shipping = 0;
    } else {
      shipping = 10;
    }

    total += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price")) || 0;
  });

  if (!total)
    shipping = 0;

  $('.total').html('$ ' + (parseFloat($("#digital").val()) + total + shipping).toFixed(2));
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input type="number" name="digital" id="digital" class="price" value="0">

  <select name="book" id="book" class="price">
    <option data-price="0" value="">Please Select</option>
    <option data-price="10.00" value="1">Book A</option>
    <option data-price="15.00" value="2">Book B</option>
  </select>

  <input data-price="7.80" class="price" name="covers[]" type="checkbox" value="1">White
  <input data-price="7.80" class="price" name="covers[]" type="checkbox" value="2">Black

  <div class="total"></div>
</form>
```

since you dont want shippincosts when the total value is `0`, you can just check it before you build the output. Adding this `if` with total *(negated)* enters the `if` if the value is `0` and sets the shippingcosts to `0`.

Actually you could remove the whole digital `if` and place it where I put the total check. Like this:

```
$(document).on('change keyup', '.price', function() {
  var total = 0;
  var shipping = 0;
  var digital = $("#digital").val();
  var test = $("#book option:selected").data("price");


  $('#form option:selected, #form input:checked').each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).attr("data-price")) || 0;
  });

  if (!total) {
      shipping = 0;
  } else {
      shipping = 10;
  }

  $('.total').html('$ ' + (parseFloat($("#digital").val()) + total + shipping).toFixed(2));
});
```